# Off canvas menu - onclick function issue

Tags: javascript, css, off-canvas-menu

I'm currently messing around with a personal project - quite new to the frontend world.

I have an off-canvas slide in menu working, however I cannot open it again after the first time of clicking the toggle button.

I am using the onclick function and then using CSS to build the transitions in and out of the viewport.

Not sure where I am going wrong so would appreciate some help!

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Grid Challenge</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sidebar">
       <div class="close">
        <i class="material-icons" onclick="hide()">
            close
            </i>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Shop</li>
            <li>Blog</li>
            <li>About us</li>
            <li>Contact Us</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

          <header>
         <section class="logo">
            <div id="logo"><h3>minera.</h3></div>
            </section>
          </header>

          <section class="header-bottom">
            <div class="icons">
                <a href=""><i class="material-icons">search </i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="material-icons">person_outline</i></a>
                <a href=""><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></a>
            </div>

            <div class="toggle-btn" onclick ="show()">
                <span> </span>
                <span> </span>
                <span> </span>
            </div>
        </section>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.3/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.3/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap');

body{
margin:0;
height:100vh;
font-family: "Poppins";
color:#3e3e3e;
}

header{
display: flex;
margin:3em;
justify-content: center;
}

#logo h3{
font-family:"poppins";
font-size:20px;
}

.header-bottom{
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items:flex-start;
margin-top:-50px;
}


.icons{
display:inline-flex;
}

.icons a i {
    margin-left:8px;
    margin-right:8px;
    color:black;
}

.toggle-btn span{
width:25px;
height:4px;
background-color: black;
margin-top:2px;
display:block;
}


#sidebar{
position: absolute;
width:220px;
height:100%;
background:white;
left:-250px;
transition: .4s;
}

#sidebar ul li{
list-style:none;
padding-top:20px;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

#sidebar.active{
left:0;
}

#sidebar.hide{
    left:-250px;
}

.close{
display: flex;
justify-content: end;
}
```

JS

```
function show(){
document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}

function hide(){
document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to toggle one class to get the desired effect. Only set one toggle function, this will toggle the class (add the class when it doesn't excist, remove when it does excist)

**Html (only the buttons with the toggle function)**

```
<i class="material-icons" onclick="toggle()">
  close
</i>

<div class="toggle-btn" onclick ="toggle()">
  <span> </span>
    <span> </span>
    <span> </span>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function toggle(){
  document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
```

**Css**

```
#sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  width:220px;
  height:100%;
  background:white;
  left:-250px;
  transition: .4s;
}

#sidebar.active{
  left:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call show() on click of X(close button).
Please note CSS is minified(It is same CSS what is mention in question).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@v4.0.0/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Grid Challenge</title>
</head>
<style>
    @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins&display=swap);body{margin:0;height:100vh;font-family:Poppins;color:#3e3e3e}header{display:flex;margin:3em;justify-content:center}#logo h3{font-family:poppins;font-size:20px}.header-bottom{display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:flex-start;margin-top:-50px}.icons{display:inline-flex}.icons a i{margin-left:8px;margin-right:8px;color:#000}.toggle-btn span{width:25px;height:4px;background-color:#000;margin-top:2px;display:block}#sidebar{position:absolute;width:220px;height:100%;background:#fff;left:-250px;transition:.4s}#sidebar ul li{list-style:none;padding-top:20px;padding-bottom:20px}#sidebar.active{left:0}#sidebar.hide{left:-250px}.close{display:flex;justify-content:end}
</style>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="close">
        <i class="material-icons" onclick="show()">
            close
        </i>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Shop</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>About us</li>
        <li>Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<header>
    <section class="logo">
        <div id="logo"><h3>minera.</h3></div>
    </section>
</header>
<section class="header-bottom">
    <div class="icons">
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">search </i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">person_outline</i></a>
        <a href=""><i class="material-icons">shopping_cart</i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="toggle-btn" onclick="show()">
        <span> </span>
        <span> </span>
        <span> </span>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.3/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.3/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
<script>
function show(){
    document.getElementById('sidebar').classList.toggle('active');
}
</script>
</html>
```